# Max total threads per thread group and gpu cores on apple machines

Tags: swift, gpu, apple-m1, metal

I’m pretty new to writing code for the GPU. I’m using the variable `MTLComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` to get the number of threads I can use. On my Intel MacBook with an intel chip and internal graphics I get 1024. On my other machine (with apple M1) I also get 1024. Doesn't this variable tell me how many threads the machine can run in parallel so shouldn’t the number be higher on a newer machine?

I tried to find information online but I couldn’t.

Comment: In general, no, “max threads” is not the same as “how many threads … can run in parallel”. For discussion about max total threads per thread group, specifically used in minimizing low occupancy problems, see [Metal Compute on MacBook Pro](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10580/?time=1150) tech talk.

Comment: No, this variable tells you how many threads you can dispatch, not how many you can run in parallel. The `threadExecutionWidth` will tell you hpw many threads can run in parallel. Also don't think of those as actual threads, they are just instances of kernel function (so they are not directly mapped to hardware, although they do depend on it).

Comment: To reiterate, there can be more than one threadgroup running in parallel, but the threadgroup size is limited. Also, threads in threadgroup don't necessarily even run in parallel.